# For each positive integer $a$, does there exist a positive integer $b$ such that $2b^2 + b \gt ab^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The problem is this: Prove or give a counterexample to the following statement. For each positive integer $a$, there exists a positive integer $b$ such that
$2b^2 + b \gt ab^2$.

I've tried a couple of things but I can't figure out a way to prove this, neiher can I find a counterexample (I'm pretty sure it's a true statement, but I could be wrong)

Edit. Actually it is quite easy to find a counterexample now that I think of it. But how would one go about proving something like this if it was provable?

Comment: Surely we cannot find such a $b$ if $a$ is large, like $10$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For all postitive integers $b$ we have $b^2 \geq b$. So for all $a\geq 3$, we have $$ab^2 \geq 3b^2 \geq 2b^2+b$$
Therefore $2b^2+b>ab^2$ cannot hold.

For $a=1$ and $a=2$ we choose $b=1$.

Answer (score 1):

You can' prove it because it's false: (1) Simplify : If $b$ is a positive integer, then :   $$ 2b^2+b>ab^2$$   if and only if  $$b(2b+1)>ab^2$$   if and only if   $$2b+1>ab$$ if and only if  (by dividing by $ b$)  $$ 2+1/b>a$$. (2)Analyze : "$b$ is a positive integer" $ \implies$   $$1\geq 1/b   \implies $$$$ 3 \geq 2+1/b.$$  (3)Combine. $$3 \geq 2+1/b>a  \implies  3>a.$$  So the main question cannot be true if $$a\geq 3.$$